# Importing syntax highlighting into Joe Editor from a different editor?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, joe-editor

Does anyone know of/have any good syntax highlights for Joe?

I like the editor, but I can't stand the syntax highlighting that comes with Joe by default. I really like the default syntax highlighting that comes with other editors like Vim, nano, or notepad++, but joe's... yeah.

Is there any simple way to import the syntax highlighting from Vim or nano or notepad++ (heh) or the likes into joe? I tried to look into changing the syntax highlighting in joe, but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

The github user [cmur2](https://github.com/cmur2) (Christian Nicolai) has a great collection of improved syntax highlights for JOE.

https://github.com/cmur2/joe-syntax

The repository includes a README.md which explains how to use the improved syntax highlighting configs.